# Elementary os music player

Tags: music

I have Elementary os Hera (5.1.7). When I try to open the Music player with a music CD (WAV files), in the media player, the music player won't stay open. It opens when I click on it and it closes in about 5 seconds.

Comment: Ditto; if I try to run it from a command line I get: ** (io.elementary.music:20043): ERROR **: 05:55:16.970: LocalLibrary.vala:151: No provider 'SQLite' installed
Trace/breakpoint trap

Comment: I did find /usr/share/applications/io.elementary.music.desktop. No idea why a dependency is missing. Can't uninstall with AppCentre. After running through that routine a couple of times, AppCentre kept Music on the installed list but acted like it wasn't installed, then no change after reinstalling.

Comment: Perhaps `Application state not set as installed in AppCenter for package: Music` is a clue, but I don't know how to toggle that state manually.